# File path error with forward slash at beginning of path

Tags: php

I have a folder with a bunch of articles that all use the same header and footer, which are in an `includes/` folder. I also needed to add another file that *is not* an article and I therefore do not want it in the folder with the other articles, but instead in the `includes/` folder. I still want it to use the same header and footer as the articles though, so naturally I just use a command like

`include 'article_header.php';`

The error is inside the header, which has `include` commands inside of *it*. Because the `article_header.php` file is built for the articles, the `include` commands inside of it look like the following:

```
<?php
    include 'includes/article_social_container.php';
    include 'includes/article_search_container.php';
    include 'includes/membership_container.php';
?>
```

Since this obviously is not going to work for the file *inside* the `includes/` folder. So I tried using a forward slash and starting from the root directory so it works for any file that uses it.

```
<?php
    include '/root/folder/includes/article_social_container.php';
    //other code
?>
```

However, this does not seem to work. I have had trouble with the forward slash at the beginning of a file path in the past, but it has also worked for me other times.

Also, why wouldn't someone always use a forward slash and start at the root directory, just to keep things safe? It probably is the answer to this question because it seems totally sensible to me unless it was for a similar purpose of the `open_basedir()` function in php.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Best to define a site root constant that can be dynamically determined depending on location of files, then use this go stand throughout the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php#constant.dir) magic constant. It resolves to the directory of the script in which it appears. Using this, you only need to use relative paths, for example...

```
// within the "includes" directory
include __DIR__ . '/article_social_container.php';
```

Another option is to configure your application's `include_path`. Say you have a script `bootstrap.php` in your `includes` directory with the following...

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, [
    __DIR__, // the "includes" directory
    get_include_path()
]));
```

This will add the `includes` directory to the top of your `include_path` stack. You can then simply do the following from any other script...

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/includes/bootstrap.php';

include 'article_header.php';
```

Any included scripts from this point on will have the same `include_path` configuration so they in turn can simply use...

```
include 'article_social_container.php';
include 'article_search_container.php';
// etc
```

Comment: I'm still so confused about `__DIR__`... so it simply returns the current directory you are in? I'm really a beginner to PHP.

Comment: It resolves to the current directory of the script in which it appears. This differs on a script-by-script basis

Comment: Now I'm starting to understand... so even if I include the `header.php` in a folder one up from `includes/`, the includes inside of `header.php` will have a path relative to the placement of `header.php`?

Comment: Only if you prefix them with `__DIR__`. Otherwise, the standard CWD (current working directory) is that of the file at the top of the *include tree*, ie the script containing the first `include`. Given the way you've structured your files, I highly recommend using the `include_path` configuration I've outlined above.

Comment: Okay, now I've got something happening, but unfortunately it's an error. It says `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/data/` _numbers_ `/user/` _number_ `/htdocs/search_me/includes/search_me_global funcs_and_vars.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/services/vux/lib/php') in /data/` _numbers_ `/user/` _number_ `/htdocs/search_me/includes/search_me_custom_header.php on line 40` Is there something wrong with the `include_path`?

Comment: @codeshackel Well, it looks like you haven't modified the `include_path`. Does that file exist? It appears to have a space in the name, is that right? If you can't work it out, I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: Wait... It's working! Thanks so much! You were hitting the nail on the head all along.